# couldn't get data while connecting mule with linkedin

Tags: mule, linkedin-api, mule-studio

I tried to integrate linkedin with mule. I successfully authorize user and also get my profile information.

But I couldn't change my current status.. And I couldn't get user updates.
I got following error

```
Message               : Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.List, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}".
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-65237
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.List, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper:268 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.List, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:268)
    at org.mule.module.linkedin.processors.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.transform(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:279)
    at org.mule.module.linkedin.processors.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAndTransform(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:202)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

My flow is as follow

```
<flow name="linkedinFlow">

       <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8090" path="auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>

         <linkedin:authorize config-ref="LinkedIn" doc:name="LinkedIn"/> 
    </flow>

<flow name="linkedinFlow2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8090" path="userupdates" doc:name="HTTP"/>

        <linkedin:get-user-updates config-ref="LinkedIn" doc:name="LinkedIn">
            <linkedin:update-types ref="#[payload]"/>
        </linkedin:get-user-updates>

        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
```

How can I get user user updates??

I also Tried following code

```
<flow name="linkedinFlow3">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8090" path="userupdates1" doc:name="HTTP" />
         <linkedin:get-network-updates config-ref="LinkedIn" start="10"
                              count="20"
                              showHiddenMembers="true"
                              startDate="2011-08-10T00:00:00-00:00"
                              endDate="2015-05-10T00:00:00-00:00">
    <linkedin:update-types>
        <linkedin:update-type>PROFILE_UPDATE</linkedin:update-type>
        <linkedin:update-type>RECOMMENDATION_UPDATE</linkedin:update-type>
    </linkedin:update-types>
</linkedin:get-network-updates> 
    </flow>
```

**Then**  I got following error

```
Exception stack is:
1. Access to network denied (com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException)
  com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient:2088 (null)
2. Failed to invoke getNetworkUpdates. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.linkedin.processors.GetNetworkUpdatesMessageProcessor:189 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
```

I also change the scope **rw_nus+r_basicprofile** but got 403 error my page didn't authenticate

If I used rw_company_admin scope I can authenticate succesfully but didn't get success in geting user updates

How can I solve this problem?please help